# How to web scrape values from a script tag and or console

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

I have a python program running on heroku/flask. Basically, I receive **two** webhooks. The **first webhook** starts a stopwatch. The **second webhook** should grab the current value of the stopwatch.

I am struggling to grab the current value of the stopwatch. It seems there are two options. Grab the value from the actual variable via webscraping or print the values to the console and grab them from there. I was thinking about using Beautiful soup but was not sure how to grab the actual value when the stopwatch is running.

The code below shows you my html file that I am rendering using python. **How can I grab the specific 'sec' variable from the program when the stopwatch is running? Or how can I grab information that is being printed to the console?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="stopwatch-container">
        <div id="stopwatch">00:00:00</div>
        <button onclick="pause()">Stop</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        var stopwatch = document.getElementById("stopwatch");
        var startBtn = document.getElementById("start-btn");
        var timeoutId = null;
        var ms = 0;
        var sec = 0;
        var min = 0;
        start();
        
        /* function to start stopwatch */
        function start(flag) {
            if (flag) {
                startBtn.disabled = true;
            }
 
            timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
                ms = parseInt(ms);
                sec = parseInt(sec);
                min = parseInt(min);
                console.log(sec) // here you can see I am logging the sec value. 
 
                ms++;
 
                if (ms == 100) {
                    sec = sec + 1;
                    ms = 0;
                }
                if (sec == 60) {
                    min = min + 1;
                    sec = 0;
                }
                if (ms < 10) {
                    ms = '0' + ms;
                }
                if (sec < 10) {
                    sec = '0' + sec;
                }
                if (min < 10) {
                    min = '0' + min;
                }
 
                stopwatch.innerHTML = min + ':' + sec + ':' + ms;
 
                // calling start() function recursivly to continue stopwatch
                start();
 
            }, 10); // setTimeout delay time 10 milliseconds
        }
 
        /* function to pause stopwatch */
        function pause() {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            startBtn.disabled = false;
        }
 
        /* function to reset stopwatch */
        function reset() {
            ms = 0;
            sec = 0;
            min = 0;
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            stopwatch.innerHTML = '00:00:00';
            startBtn.disabled = false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Grab the value" where?  You're already using the value in your Javascript.  If you want your Python code to see it, you'll have to make an AJAX request.  You certainly wouldn't want to do that 10 times a second.  Remember, after your Python code sends the HTML, that connection is severed.  There is no longer any pipe between the browser and the server.  The browser has to open a NEW pipe.

Comment: So how can I grab that value using my python program? Do you have an example with AJAX?

Comment: I understand that connection is severed, but I am asking what the best way to grab those values are when my second webhook comes in. Should I try and web scrape it from the script tag? Or should I try and grab that information from the info that is being printed to the console? How would I do either of those?

Comment: @TimRoberts I would not need to make the request 10 times a second. ***I only need my python script to see the value when it receives the second webhook.***

Comment: You can't "grab" the values.  If you want the Javascript code to send something to Python, then you have to use an AJAX request to send the value of the `stopwatch` element.

Comment: Okay! That I can do. Thank you. For future reference, is it possible to grab information that is being printed on the console? The console you see when you inspect an element that is.

Comment: No, but the Javascript is in control.  Anything it writes to the console can be written to a string array for safekeeping.